# Ng-repeat y número máximo decimales

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<td ng-repeat="val in values">
    {{val : number:2}}  => Me muestra 2 decimales
    <input type="number" step="any" ng-model="valor[$index]" ng-init="valor[$index]=val" />
</td>
```

Necesito que el valor del input solo tenag dos decimales y no 6 por ejemplo

Comment: Podrías hacer una directiva que tome el valor y lo formatee cada vez que cambie le valor. Yo te recomiendo que formatee una vez que hace `blur()` del input, lo otro genera varios problemas.

Answer (score 0):

A ver si te sirve asi:

```
<input type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" ng-model="valor[$index]" ng-init="valor[$index]=val" />
```

Comment: me sale en rojo el recuadro del input pero no me lo formatea automaticamente

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)